# How to retrieve TimerJob Schedule Configuration via code c#

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I need  retrieve via code, what's the schedule configuration of a Timerjob. 
Exe: for a Timerjob scheduled weekly, to get the value "weekly".

Answer (score 1):

```
var spFarm = SPFarm.Local;
var timerJob = spFarm.TimerService.JobDefinitions.OfType<SPJobDefinition>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "Timer Job Name");
```

and then take a look at `timerJob.Schedule` object.

Comment: No meant about the Timejob that is current running. I should not iterate any TimerJob  in Farm

Answer (score 0):

Try below function

```
string GetTimerJobStatus(string timerJobName) 
{
    string schedule = string.Empty;

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => 
    { 
        SPWebApplication webApp = SPContext.Current.CurrentWeb.WebApplication;
        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webApp.JobDefinitions)
        {
            if (job.Name.Equals(timerJobName))
            {
                schedule = job.Schedule.GetType().FullName;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    return schedule;
}
```